# I want to show nested subcategories products in subcategories section

Tags: wordpress

I have a parent category and inside that I have a sub-category, and also inside that I have 4 more nested sub-categories, so I choose to display "Show Sub-Category" in "Category Display" but what I want is inside the sub-category I just want to show all the products from those 4 nested sub-categories.

I want some expert who can give me a solution on how to do it manually without any plugins. I hope my question is easy to understand, and if not please ping me and I'll explain in more detail.